# WPF Datagrid - Can I programmatically select all rows in a Group?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping

Regards,

I have a DataGrid with a checkbox column to allow the user to select rows, a "select all" checkbox in the column header, and a "select all" checkbox in the group header.

XAML:

```xml
 <DataGrid x:Name="TablaDatos"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
            CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
            CanUserResizeRows="True" 
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            Grid.Row="2">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#A0FAFAFF" Offset="0.3" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFAACAFF" Offset="1" />
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Expander.Background>
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <CheckBox x:Name="ProyectoCHK" Margin="0 5 0 0" Click="ProyectoCHK_Click"></CheckBox>
                                                <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="200" Target="{Binding ElementName=ProyectoCHK}"/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="0 5 0 0"/>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="theCheckbox"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Id. Prueba" Binding="{Binding id_prueba}" SortDirection="Descending"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="VSAT" Binding="{Binding VSAT}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="PC" Binding="{Binding PC}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Fecha Evento" Binding="{Binding FechaUltimoEvento, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss\}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Estado" Binding="{Binding Estado}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Mensaje" Binding="{Binding Mensaje}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Fecha de creación" Binding="{Binding FechaCreacionPrueba}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Proyecto" Binding="{Binding PROYECTO}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Departamento" Binding="{Binding DEPARTAMENTO}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Municipio" Binding="{Binding MUNICIPIO}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Localidad" Binding="{Binding LOCALIDAD}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Id. punto" Binding="{Binding IDENTIFICADOR_PUNTO}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Usuario" Binding="{Binding UsuarioPrueba}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

¿How I Can Select all Checkboxes for the rows in a group?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the CheckBox "ProyectoCHK"'s Checked event do this... (code below may need improvements)

1. The visual sibling of `ProyectoCHK` is a Label which is bound to the Name property in `GroupStyle`. Access that and copy its Content into a variable say "GroupValue".
2. Assuming that you have bound your `DataGrid` to a `CollectionView`, when grouping happens you have the `GroupDescription` in it.

So accessing that will give you the `GroupedPropertyName` on which grouping has happened. Then you can use

```
     var items = DataGrid.ItemsSource.AsQueryable.Where(GroupedPropertyName + " == " + "\"" + GroupValue + "\"");
```

`AsQueryable()` is available in Linq namespace.

1. The `items` returned by the query filter above, just make individual `item.Checked = true` (Assuming that item class has implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has raised `PropertyChanged` notification for `Checked` property).

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVVM pattern you can just set the bound CheckBox property in your view-model to "True" and the CheckBox control will reflect the value